# The og:title doesn't show

Tags: html, share, facebook-opengraph, blogger

I've been working on a blog (blogger) for a friend, and she want's the shared posts to show the post title and not the blog title... How can I accomplish this?
I've already tried to delete the title tag...
    `<meta property="og:title"/>`
But the result is the same... What line of code should i delete or add?
Now, I only have this 4 lines of og code
`<meta content='http://lostinthegoodlife.blogspot.com/' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rVflDp3_oW8/VajTpnLQAxI/AAAAAAAAAig/stX7spBEFts/s320/rita2.jpg?t=12345?' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='567' property='og:image:width'/>
<meta content='567' property='og:image:height'/>`

It's my first time editing code on blogger and i'm not really familiarized whit it... So could anybody help?

Comment: Do you always try the same url? Facebook does caching so if it downloaded the url without these tags, you need to force it to re-download.

Comment: @Jakuje I'v debugged the url (I think that what you're talking about) with developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: @Jakuje is there a line that i can insert saying that the title to show is the post title and not the blog title?

Comment: This requires some more information to be answered correctly. How do you render the blog posts? The problem with this code is that you will always get the same title / url / image no matter the blog post.

Comment: @XelharK The blog image and url are always the same... The title's the only thing that changes...

Comment: Ok, then that tag has to be filled by the same technology you're using to render the rest of the page, otherwise it will never work. 

Basically, this is not an HTML problem. It depends on your technology. What are you using? PHP? ASP? Wordpress? Or maybe you're using some client-side technology like Angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Ensuring correct title of the article**

Go to your template editor and paste this(Make necessary changes where applicable in the below code)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://www.YOOURBLOG.BLOGSPOT.COM/2014/12/YOUR ARTICLE URL.html&quot;'>

<meta content='Can you guess what do these World Maps Indicate ?' property='og:title'/>    
<meta content='http://www.YOOURBLOG.BLOGSPOT.COM/2014/12/YOUR ARTICLE URL.html' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='The Best thing on the Internet,today!' property='og:description'/>
<meta content='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XO6XJlYyh6M/VbONBkKs8CI/AAAAAAAANbk/Dt-wbrYGSwY/w1200-h628-no/map%2Bquiz.jpg' property='og:image'/>

</b:if>
```

**Step 2: Ensuring FB cache is cleared**

Go to 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Click on `debug`
Then click on `Fetch New scrape information`.